# Ist der Satz "Ich kaufe einen Cheese Burger und einen Vegetarischen Burger" richtig?

Tags: grammar, adjective-ending

Ist dieser Satz richtig?

> Ich kaufe einen Cheese Burger und einen Vegetarischen Burger.

Wenn ja, warum haben wir dann kein `-en` am Ende von `Cheese`? Ist es, weil Cheese kein deutsches Wort ist?

Comment: Warum nur mag jemand, der sich dauernd oder fallweise vegetarisch ernähren möchte - eine Haltung, mit der ich ausdrücklich symphatisiere - einen Fleisch-Klops kaufen?

Comment: @Ingo: Nicht jeder, der einen Veggi-Burger isst, ist ein Vegetarier. Auch Mischkostesser verzehren gelegentlich vegetarische Nahrungsmittel. Außerdem kann eine einzelne Person auch Burger für mehrere Personen kaufen. Käufer und Konsumenten sind nicht dasselbe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weil die anderen die gestellte Frage noch nicht beantwortet haben:

**Nein**, der Satz ist nicht richtig. Richtig wäre:

> Ich kaufe einen Cheeseburger und einen vegetarischen Burger.

»Cheeseburger« ist im Deutschen ein zusammengesetztes Hauptwort, das aus den beiden Hauptwörtern »Cheese« und »Burger« besteht (beides sind englische Fremdwörter). Es ist vergleichbar mit »Käsebrot«, das aus »Käse« und »Brot« zusammengesetzt ist.

Das Wort »vegetarischen« ist der Dativ eines Eigenschaftsworts (Dativ weil der Burger, der diese Eigenschaft hat, selbst im Dativ steht). Und da dieses Wort weder am Anfang eines Satzes steht noch ein Hauptwort ist, schreibt man es klein.

Answer (score 6):

Cheeseburger wird zusammengeschrieben und kommt aus dem Englischen. Richtig wäre: „Ich kaufe einen Cheeseburger und einen vegetarischen Burger.“

Answer (score 5):

[Cheeseburger](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeseburger) (ohne Leerzeichen) ist eine Produktbezeichnung oder Eigenname. "Cheese-Burger" ist die Übernahme der englischen Schreibweise.

Einen "**V**egetarischen Burger" empfinde ich als einen unglücklichen Ausdruck. Entweder es ist ein **v**egetarischer Burger (d. h., der Burger wird mit einem Adjektiv näher beschrieben) oder, als Eigenbegriff, ein [Veggie-Burger](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veggie-Burger).

Comment: Ich hielte zwar auch „Vegetarischer Burger“ für einen nicht besonders einfallsreichen Namen, aber Adjektive, die Teil von Eigennamen sind, werden im allgemeinen gebeugt: „Außenminister Frank-Walter Steinmeier sagte der Süddeutschen Zeitung, [...]™. In der Werbung scheint das allerdings aus der Mode zu kommen.

Comment: [Eigenname](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenname) wohl weniger - Eiffelturm wäre ein Eigenname, weil es nur einen gibt. Cheeseburger gibt es wie Sand am Meer. Und dict.leo.org spuckt mir einen cheeseburger aus.

Answer (score 3):

Auch Käseburger wäre ein zusammengesetztes Substantiv, "vegetarisch" hingegen ist ein Adjektiv.